# C# throws a ConfigurationErrorsException upon loading App.config

Tags: c#, io, configuration-files

The only solutions I've been able to find on this subject is to add the keys inside the appSettings tag, but as you can see I have already done that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="customFilename" value="55"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The code loading the value throws an error here

```
private void reloadConfigFile()
{
    MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["customFilename"]);
}
```

I've even copied and pasted someone else's App.config file, which was working for them, and it still failed to compile. What did I miss?

Comment: Can you give us the exception details and stack trace?

Comment: I found the issue. Visual studio created an "App.config" file while I saw other people using "app.config" I tried renaming it and it is now working fine.